# Prevent checkbox from getting checked when confirm box cancel is clicked in angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a checkbox and on click i am showing a confirm box.It is getting checked when "OK" is clicked in the confirm box.That is fine.
I want to prevent it from getting checked when the "CANCEL" is clicked in the confirm box?
It is getting checked everytime i am clicking cancel in the confirm box?

**The code is in the below**

```
<input ng-model="checkboxValue" ng-click="makeLive(row)" type="checkbox">

$scope.makeLive = function (row)
{
    if ($window.confirm("Sure to make it live?Can't edit after making it live.") === true)
    {
        alert("id====" + row.entity.id);

    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your <input> tag is in row ? I mean input tag is inside `ng-repeat` or something?

Comment: yes  it is repeated through ng-grid

Comment: So you need ng-model value should be different for each row's checkbox... Check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197706/2210514 if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since we've discovered that this code is now being repeated...**

...you will need to change your `ng-model` to a variable that belongs to the `row` object (whatever that is). This will prevent conflicting checkbox clicks from overriding one another.

So your HTML now becomes:

```
<input ng-model="row.isLive" ng-click="makeLive(row)" type="checkbox">
```

Then assign the `row.isLive` value to the return value of the `$window.confirm()` function:

```
$scope.makeLive = function(row) {

  row.isLive = $window.confirm(
    "Sure to make it live? Can't edit after making it live."
  );

  if (row.isLive){
    // do something (if you want to)
  else{
    // do something else (if you need to)
  }
};
```

**Demo**

[**CodePen: Using $window.confirm() to continue-to (or cancel-from) checking a checkbox**](https://codepen.io/mjcwly/pen/MEWNdJ)

Comment: @Samim Any feedback on this approach?

Comment: @Samim Okay, would you be able to explain more precisely which part is not working in relation to [this demo](https://codepen.io/mjcwly/pen/MEWNdJ) of the proposed solution?

Comment: I was not using ng-repeat , i was using ng-grid options in that case it was not working now i used ng-repeat and your code works..thanks ..accepting it as correct ..cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the user cancels it. you can just use `preventDefault`. like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ifs').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input ng-model="checkboxValue" id="ifs" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: that can be done by using jquery and angularjs have also its own way

Comment: ab29007   ,  i know how to do in jquery but it is not on the click function of the checkbox it is on the value returned from the confirm box.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as below code :-)

```
<input ng-model="checkboxValue" ng-click="makeLive(row)" type="checkbox">


$scope.makeLive = function (row)
{
    if ($window.confirm("Sure to make it live?Can't edit after making it live.") === true)
    {
        alert("id====" + row.entity.id);

    } else
    {
        $scope.checkboxValue = false;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: i have edited the code please check once again _ng-checked='checked'_ no need of function over there and before return false there is one line _$scope.checked = false_

Comment: It is working just for the first time.When Clicked second time it is getting checked again

Comment: the checkbox are repating in ng-grid

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: I mean the checkbox are generated through a loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154340/discussion-between-prateik-and-samim).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one -

```
  <input ng-model="checkboxValue[$index]" ng-click="makeLive(row, $index)" type="checkbox">
```

And function in JS code will be-

```
     $scope.makeLive = function (row, index)
     {
        if ($window.confirm("Sure to make it live?Can't edit after making it live.") === true)
        {
           alert("id====" + row.entity.id);

        } else
        {
           $scope.checkboxValue[index] = false;
           return false;
        }
     };
```

Comment: not working..it is still getting checked after clicking cancel

Comment: $index means the incremental key of loop have u defined that key by $index?

Comment: yes `$index` is current loop index and we assigned it to `ng-model` variable to make it unique..
Can u share code with `ng-repeat` and row inside more clarification to find out root cause?